# Find out if my dongle is AP capable

Tags: wireless

I'd like to turn my Raspberry PI into an access point.
I've read that my wifi dongle has to have an AP mode (here's my dongle:
https://www.modmypi.com/raspberry-pi-accessories/wireless-usb-1n-nano-adaptor-802.11N-wifi-dongle) and that typing from the console:

```
iw list
```

I should get the information but all I get is:

nl80211 not found

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the picture, you have the same wifi dongle as I do.

Check this [site](http://www.jenssegers.be/). It is written to hostap, but i think will lead you to the right answer.

But in resume, the realtek has it own modules. You need to download it and install by hand.

I used it for hostap and it work, but i still don't have the iw command.